# Linear System: Symmetric Under Time Reversal?

Tags: linear-systems

In class, my professor mentioned that "Linear systems must be symmetric under time reversal" in an off-handed way and did not clarify further. I assume this is true, but I'm not sure how one would show this based off the definition of linear that I once learned.

I'm assuming symmetric under time reversal means:
$$x(n) = x(-n)$$

How is this shown by the definition of linearity?
$$a x_1(n) + b x_2(n) \rightarrow a y_1(n) + b y_2(n) $$

Comment: You need to ask your prof.  It could be that they were teaching about some specific subject and they meant that the linear systems _that they were talking about that day_ needed to be time-symmetric.  Otherwise I don't think the statement makes much sense as it stands.

Answer (score 1):

I can't know what your professor meant, but what can be shown quite easily for linear time-invariant systems is that time-reversing the input **and** the system's impulse response will result in a time-reversed output. Let $x[n]$ and $h[n]$ be the input signal and the impulse response, respectively. Then the output is given by the convolution sum

$$y[n]=\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}x[k]h[n-k]\tag{1}$$

Now we define the time-reversed input and impulse response by

$$x^-[n]=x[-n],\qquad h^-[n]=h[-n]$$

The convolution sum of these two sequences is the time-reversed output $y[-n]$:

\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}x^-[k]h^-[n-k] &= \sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}x[-k]h[-n+k] \\
&= \sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}x[k]h[-n-k] \\
&= y[-n]
\end{align*}

Note that both, $x[n]$ and $h[n]$ need to be time-reversed in order to obtain a time-reversed output.

Comment: Wouldn’t the system need to be time invariant? The OP only mentions “linear”

Comment: @Jdip: Yes, I assumed time-invariance. I believe that this is what must be meant, even though you're right that in the question it only says "linear".